# How to add listener to table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener

I am trying to add a listener to JTable that delete a selected rows.

I have a class ToolBar in which contains all the buttons, 
but all my JTable setting is on another class: TablePanel.

I want to be able to delete row(s) when the user click a buttons in ToolBar Class.

**ToolBar.java**

```
public class ToolBar extends JPanel
{

TablePanel tablePane;

JButton openButton, saveButton, addButton, delButton;
ImageIcon openIcon, saveIcon, addIcon, delIcon;
Image openImage, saveImage, addImage, delImage;
Image openImage2, saveImage2, addImage2, delImage2;

ButtonListener listener;

public ToolBar(TablePanel tablePane)
{

    this.tablePane = tablePane;

    //Bunch of codes here to initialize all the buttons and icons
}

//Button Listener
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

        if (event.getSource() == openButton)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hello");
        if (event.getSource() == saveButton)
            tablePane.saveData();
        if (event.getSource() == addButton)
            tablePane.addRow();
        if (event.getSource() == delButton)
            tablePane.delRow();


    }

}

}
```

**TablePanel**

```
public class TablePanel extends JPanel
{

//Table's column name
private ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();


//List of data, later needs to be change 
//so that it will be editable on the go
//It starts with 5 columns 
//User can add more columns 
private ArrayList<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();


//DefaultTableModel is needed for adding new rows
private JTable table;
private TModel tModel;

private JScrollPane scrollPane;

//For importing & exporting data
JFileChooser fileChooser;


public TablePanel()
{

    //Column Names:
    columnNames.add("Date");
    columnNames.add("Category");
    columnNames.add("Details");
    columnNames.add("Add/Subtract");
    columnNames.add("Total");

    //Example data:
    data.add(new Object[]{20140925, "Grocery", "Supermarket", -5.23,600.00});
    data.add(new Object[]{20141013,"Car Maintenance", "Changing Tires", -200.00, 400.00});



        //Some codes here
}
private class TModel extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModelListener
{
    //Bunch of codes(methods) in here such as:
    //public voide setValueAt, public Boolean isCellEditable, getColumnCount etc.
    //Method for deleting row
    public void delRow()
    {

    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent event)
    {

        int row = event.getFirstRow();
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
    }

    }


} //End of TModel class



} //End of TablePanel Class
```

How should I implement listener and fireTableDeleted(int row)?
What should I add in the *public void delRow()*?

[image]

Comment: Don't create a custom TableModel. The DefaultTableModel supports all the functionalilty you require. You can dynamically add/remove rows or change the data in any cell of the table.

Comment: Yeah I know that DefaultTableModel support addRow and removeRows automatically.  But it doesn't support the isCellEditable() function from what I heard, that's why I use AbstractTableModel.  I try to look into DefaulTableModel class so that I can copy the code from that class and paste it into AbstractTableModel, but somehow I can't look into the source code.  May it's because closed source?  Also I need to specify column's data type later, not sure if it's good to use DefaultTableModel though.

Comment: `But it doesn't support the isCellEditable() function`, sure it does, you just override the IsCellEditable(...)method to implement your custom logic. `Also I need to specify column's data type later,` same solution. You override the getColumnClass(...) method. There is no need to create a completely new TableModel just to override methods of the model. This is a standard practice for any Java class, not just a TableModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone is going to need a reference to someone else, but you also want to maintain a level of separation so you don't end up tightly coupling your components together

You could use a controller of some kind, which has a reference to the table and is either listening directly to the buttons on the toolbar or which the tool bar can call and instruct it on what it wants to do.

For example, when clicked, the delete button would simply instruct the controller to "delete the selected rows".  The controller would ask the `TablePane` to "Delete the selected rows" and the `TablePane` would comply.

This could be achieved through the [Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) API where the `Action` would act as the controller.

Basically you would create a new `DeleteRowAction` (this is class you'd have to create), which had a reference to the `TablePane` and which you would pass to the `ToolBar` pane.  You would then apply the `Action` to the delete button (`JButton#setAction`) and let it take care of everything else for you

Comment: Ah Okey, I kind of understand what you are saying, but not all of it >_< Me still a newbie Q.Q   Say if I want the TableModelListener only activate in a single method but not other methods, should I implement in the above way?  (I change my TablePanel.java: the TModel class now implements TableModelListener, and I put the ActionPerformed within delRow())  I don't have Eclipse to help me verify at the moment of posting.